# AngularJS - Sync scrolling two divs lags, out of sync when dealing with large data

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have successfully synced the scrolling of a few divs based on a single master DIV as so with such a directive (Vertical, and horizontal versions):

```
app.directive('verticalScroll', [function () {
    function scrollSlave(master, slave) {
        if (!slave) return;          
        master[0].scrollTop = slave[0].scrollTop;
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        compile: function (element, attrs) {
            var master = element.find('.s-context'),
                slave = element.find('.s-context-col-header');
            master.on('scroll', function () {
                scrollSlave(master, slave);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

[image: Current Divs orientation]

Now inside each of these divs, contains a single table, which is generated by using ng-repeat to iterate through the list of items that I need to show.

However, I've noticed that at certain times, if I were to scroll fast enough, the divs will be out of sync (I have borders for each cell which I can tell if they are out of sync or not). This happens more often on MAC OS, from a friend of mine who noticed the problem, and less on Windows. (I use Chrome and FF as my base model). On other occasions, it will be scrolling at 1px at a time (using scroll wheel). Is there any way to mitigate this?

Comment: What amount of data we are telling here? Did you try to use an `infiniteScroll` approach in order to load parts of the data as you scroll?

Comment: No, I have not try to use an infiniteScroll approach. Because I'm loading the whole package worth of data I need, before transforming them in the front-end to present it nicely to the user.

Comment: Yes but it seems like a rendering issue because of the quantity of the data. You should either go infiteScroll or add pagination. You can use infiniteScroll source your data after you transforming to what you want.

Comment: To be honest, this is a project that generates a schedule based on various constraints such as people, skill and work hours, and I need to be able to "drag and drop", and make validation if that action will trigger any warning flags that may violate the constraints. It will be annoying to dissect them into pages since I will need to build them back in one whole again for the full validation of other cells. I can take a look at infiniteScrolls, however, thanks to your suggestion

Comment: Well I understand but this seems still like a rendering issue meaning that you have to create a strategy on how you are going to load so many data as you say. Good luck ;)

Comment: If you have any other ideas please do throw them. For now, I can turn a blind eye on this issue as not many people would just scroll that fast. (We basically just moved the mouse left and right at a very fast pace because we can, and found the issue)